Wavelets - Upsampling and downsampling relation.
Suppose $M \in \mathbb{N}, N=2 M, z \in \ell^2\left(\mathbb{Z}_N\right)$, and $w \in \ell^2\left(\mathbb{Z}_M\right)$. I need to prove that
$$
\langle D(z), w\rangle=\langle z, U(w)\rangle .
$$

Note that the inner product on the left side is in $\ell^2\left(\mathbb{Z}_M\right)$, whereas the inner product on the right is in $\ell^2\left(\mathbb{Z}_N\right)$.

How to prove this ?

What have you tried? Whilst I have to guess the definition of $U$ since its not included, I'd think that writing out both sides of the equality you want explicitly should leave you only needing to make a simple change of variables.

From left to right you insert terms with zero factors into the sum of the scalar product.
